# How to set CustomActionFilter property in Web API in .NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have a class `CustomActionFilter` that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` and it has a string property; I'll pass a value to it when annotated with `Controller Action` but in `OnActionExecuting` that string property is `NULL`.

This is my class:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorize()
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (Test == "1") // Test is null
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` method, I have:

```
services.AddControllers(p => p.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomActionFilter)));
```

And this code is in my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json", "application/problem+json")]
public class TestValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [CustomActionFilter(Test= "test")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mohsen Saleh, You register the filter for two times, actually you will hit OnActionExecuting method for two times. First time the Test is null, the second time the Test is test. Just remove the global filter.

Comment: Hi @Rena thank you  I remove the global filter and it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
services.AddControllers(p => p.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomActionFilter)));
```

with

```
services.AddControllers()
```

You have registered the filter globally and it is called twice.